# How to get total after Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer, t.state
  FROM tbl_parcel_item t
 WHERE t.courier_name='Tnt'
   AND t.date = '2018-03-12'
   AND t.ship_status NOT IN (0,1,9,10)
 GROUP BY t.state`
```

Based on the sql above the results would be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsqnM.png)
How to make it get total of the result above for example :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNmJG.png)

Comment: use sum(customer) as total

Answer (score 0):

Use [`with rollup`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer, t.state`
FROM tbl_parcel_item t
WHERE t.courier_name = 'Tnt' AND
      t.date = '2018-03-12' AND
      t.ship_status NOT IN (0, 1, 9, 10)
GROUP BY t.state WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use union all:

```
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer, t.state`
`FROM tbl_parcel_item t`
`WHERE t.courier_name='Tnt'`
`AND t.date = '2018-03-12'`
`AND t.ship_status NOT IN (0,1,9,10)`
`GROUP BY t.state`
`UNION ALL`
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer, 'Total' as state`
`FROM tbl_parcel_item t`
`WHERE t.courier_name='Tnt'`
`AND t.date = '2018-03-12'`
`AND t.ship_status NOT IN (0,1,9,10)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t.state, 'TOTAL') AS state,
    COUNT(*) AS customer
FROM tbl_parcel_item t
WHERE
    t.courier_name = 'Tnt' AND
    t.date = '2018-03-12'  AND
    t.ship_status NOT IN (0,1,9,10)
GROUP BY t.state WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

01) WITH ROLLUP as Explained in the other answers

02)
Use Union Query

```
  SELECT  t.state, COUNT(*) AS customer FROM tbl_parcel_item t WHERE t.courier_name='Tnt' AND t.date = '2018-03-12' AND t.ship_status NOT IN (0,1,9,10) GROUP BY t.state
  UNION 
  SELECT  'Total', COUNT(*) AS customer FROM tbl_parcel_item t WHERE t.courier_name='Tnt' AND t.date = '2018-03-12' AND t.ship_status NOT IN (0,1,9,10)
```